# Should I always use Recyclerview when possible?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I have a GridView that has exactly 4 children. This will never ever change, and I will assign them in onCreate every time. They aren't scrollable because they are so few. Is there any reason to use RecyclerView over GridView or GridLayout here? I know it's better optimized when you need to scroll, but does it even matter if I use RecyclerView, GridView or GridLayout if I will have a number of items that will never go off the screen?

Comment: "I have a GridView that has exactly 4 children. This will never ever change" - Well there won't be any "Recycling" of views, so, no, why use a "RecyclerView".  On the other hand, saying that something will never change can make things difficult when they do change!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance if there is not scrolling(no recycling of items) there wouldn't be a difference.